# How to locally validate AWS AppSync: Graphql Schema before uploading to AWS?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

As we develop our cloud-native applications using **AWS .NET CDK**, we are looking for ways to streamline the process and shorten the feedback loop. One aspect we are particularly interested in is validating the GraphQL schemas before uploading them to **AWS AppSync**. Is there a way to achieve this within the AWS .NET CDK framework?

Comment: Not posting as answer, since it's not the solution you want, but I don't think CDK itself is able to validate GraphQL schema. However, you can use available 3-rd party GraphQL validation libraries and invoke those as part of your build steps.

Comment: @TofigHasanov I did not find any 3-rd party library that can do that for me and it is not related to actually using GraphQL as a server (which is not my case) as I'm using Appsync, nevertheless if you find one, do share.

Comment: I think https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools library does validation as part of executing `makeExecutableSchema` method (You can also check https://graphql.org/graphql-js/). You can write a small JS utility that tries to build a schema, invoke it from your C# CDK code as a script and check if exit code is non-zero. A bit hacky, but might work.